# Getting error trying to run Homebrew via Process in a macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, terminal, homebrew

I want a macOS app using SwiftUI that displays a list of applications with checkboxes. The user checks what they want installed then clicks a Run button. Terminal opens to show debug and if the user needs to enter a password. The applications should be installed via Homebrew. I'd like the code to check if Homebrew is installed, and installs it, but I can worry about that later.

When Terminal opens, it states:

> /Users/admin/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Application: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    let command: String
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var applications: [Application] = [
        Application(name: "Brave", command: "brew install --cask brave-browser"),
        Application(name: "Chrome", command: "brew install --cask google-chrome"),
        Application(name: "DuckDuckGo", command: "brew install ddgr"),
        Application(name: "Firefox", command: "brew install --cask firefox"),
        Application(name: "Opera", command: "brew install --cask opera"),
        Application(name: "OperaGX", command: "brew install --cask opera-gx"),
        Application(name: "Acrobat Reader", command: "brew install --cask adobe-acrobat-reader"),
        Application(name: "Spotify", command: "brew install --cask spotify"),
        Application(name: "VLC Player", command: "brew install --cask vlc"),
        Application(name: "Dropbox", command: "brew install --cask dropbox"),
        Application(name: "Zoom", command: "brew install --cask zoom"),
        Application(name: "Handbrake", command: "brew install handbrake"),
        Application(name: "AVG", command: "brew install --cask avg-antivirus"),
        Application(name: "Malwarebytes", command: "brew install --cask malwarebytes"),
        Application(name: "Steam", command: "brew install --cask steam"),
        Application(name: "Epic Games", command: "brew install --cask epic-games"),
        Application(name: "Audacity", command: "brew install --cask audacity"),
        Application(name: "Discord", command: "brew install --cask discord"),
        Application(name: "Skype", command: "brew install --cask skype"),
        Application(name: "Edge", command: "brew install --cask microsoft-edge"),
        Application(name: "TeamViewer", command: "brew install --cask teamviewer"),
        Application(name: "OBS Studio", command: "brew install --cask obs"),
        Application(name: "Visual Studio", command: "brew install --cask visual-studio-code"),
        Application(name: "Sublime Text", command: "brew install --cask sublime-text"),
        Application(name: "Blizzard App", command: "brew install --cask battle-net"),
        // Add more applications here
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(applications.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: $applications[index].isSelected) {
                    Text(self.applications[index].name)
                }
            }
            
            Button("Run") {
                for app in applications {
                    if app.isSelected {
                        installApplicationWithBrew(command: app.command)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    private func installApplicationWithBrew(command: String) {
        let script = """
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script "sudo \(command)"
        end tell
        """
        var error: NSDictionary?
        if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
            scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error!)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```swift
private func installApplicationWithBrew(command: String) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "/usr/local/bin/brew \(command)"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

I tried Formula:

```swift
private func installApplicationWithBrew(formula: String) {
    let brewPath = "/opt/homebrew/bin/brew" // Use the actual path to brew here
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = ["bash", "-c", "\(brewPath) install \(formula)"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Comment: It sounds like another sandboxed-app question.

Comment: The Terminal states: /Users/admin/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew. How do I get this to install the actual Applications that get checked?

Comment: As already hinted; is the app sandboxed?

Comment: Yes. But happens outside of xcode. Or should I completely remove the sandbox option?

Comment: I found an App called, "Applite". It's exactly what I'd like to do, and more. I'm going to learn from that.